# Change Column Name on html table created via pandas

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe, django-views

I created a panda dataframe from django models. A table was created. I want to rename the column names which are in th tag. How can I do it? Here is what come. Image is in the link.

[https://ibb.co/s1VxRF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69MEZ.png)

```
    @login_required
    def totaldonation(request):
    payments = Payment.objects.all().values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(payments)

    dada = {
          "df": df.to_html(index=False, classes='table').replace('border="1"','border="0"')
```

Comment: You can specify columns in a list and pass it to column argument while calling pd.DataFrame(). Read (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). 

OR 

You can try renaming columns once the dataframe is created. Read this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 0):

When you define your columns in models.py, use verbose_name to specify what needs to be displayed when that column is accessed. Eg.,

```
    class Student(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Student Name'),
        favorite1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, \
          verbose_name='Favorite Subject 1')
```